# How would I access these variables in ThreeJS?

Tags: javascript, function, geometry

I have started to work in javascript and ThreeJS in order to do a project. It involves creating a bunch of spheres. To do that, I am using for loops and a function to create spheres. However, one thing that I dont understand is how to access the variables after creating them inside the function/loop. Inside the function a variable named sphere is being created, but how do i access that specific sphere variable

also is it possible to use a function input as a variable name?
like this:function myFunction(name)
    { var name = 3}
so that when i input numberThree into the function, it creates a variable named numberThree?

```
for(i=1; i< 5; i++)
{
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 100, 100), new     THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
sphere.overdraw = true;
scene.add(sphere);
sphere.position.x = i * 20;
}
  function drawSphere(size, x, y)
  {
  var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(size, 100, 100), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
  sphere.overdraw = true;
  scene.add(sphere);
  sphere.position.x = x;
  sphere.position.y = y;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be creating a new sphere and then adding it to the scene each time. To be able to access them individually, you'll have to make the spheres a global array first and then add them to the scene, like this:

```
 var sphere = [];
 for(i=0; i< 4; i++) // should count from zero
 {
      sphere[i] = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 100, 100),new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
      sphere[i].overdraw = true;
      scene.add(sphere[i]);
      sphere[i].position.x = i * 20;
 }
```

Then you can access each sphere by calling it specifically. For example you could change the third sphere's colour:

```
  sphere[2].material.color.setHex(0xFFFFF);
```